# How to do a search for PID? (bash)

Tags: bash, search, pid

assuming that I know the PID of a process and want to do a search in ps -A, how do I do it? I tried doing this:

```
echo "Enter PID to search: "
read PID
search=$(ps -A | grep -v PID | awk '{print $1}')
```

This returns me with a long list of PIDs. So how can I get use each individual value of the output and do:

```
if [ "$PID" = "*each_value_in_search_list*" ]; then
........
```

In this case i'm trying to compare what the user enters with the output of my command, so how do I do it? Am I doing the correct way in the first place? Or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks for your help, everyone who answered this question. (:

Comment: I do not understand why you are using `-v` flag for grep.

Comment: i was trying to remove the heading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -v switch for grep performs an inverted search, in other words you will get everything you DON'T want. After a variable is set, you should also reference it prefixed with $.

try this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter PID to search: "
read PID
search=$(ps --pid $PID -o comm=)

if [ $search ]
    then
        echo "Program: $search"
    else
        echo "No program found with PID: $PID"
fi
```

Comment: `--pid` is not supported on BSD `ps`. the `-p` option seems preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You're grepping the output of `ps` for all lines which do not contain the literal string "PID".  You want to use `$PID` instead to use the *variable* named PID instead of the literal "PID".  Furthermore, since you do not want false positives on other fields matching the PID, just match on the first column:

```
search=$(ps -A | grep "^ *$PID\>" | awk '{print $1}')
```

The `"\>"` escape sequence matches the empty string at the end of a word.

Some versions of `ps` support a `-p` option to only give you the info about a specific PID, so you don't need grep or awk:

```
search=$(ps -p $PID)
```

Comment: POSIX ps supports the -p option - so odds are good that you're not going to find a ps on a reasonably up-to-date machine which doesn't support it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `"grep -v PID"` is a standard trick to remove the heading line, not a way to get the actual PID details from the output.

If all you want is the details for that process, just use:

```
search=$(ps -A | awk -v pid=$PID '$1==pid{print pid}')
```

That will set search to the PID in question if it exists or the empty string otherwise, which is what you appear to want.

There's a problem with doing a blind search for the PID (as opposed to checking column 1 with `awk`) is that you may pick up lines where that PID shows up in the command string.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `grep` you could [use the `-p` option to pass the PID directly to the `ps` command](http://research.att.com/~gsf/man/man1/ps.html).

Answer (score 2):

If the root of the question is to check if the entered PID corresponds to a process entry (root). More specific, if you are able to send a signal to that process (user):

```
if kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...
```

It could be, of course, that this is not at all what you want. I felt free to "interpret" your question a bit ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("ps -Ao cmd,pid|grep -P ' {$pid}$'");
?>
```